# How to fix video and audio out-of-sync (sometimes)?

Tags: audio, video, sync, tv

I have a avi video file which plays perfectly on Linux (using e.g. `mplayer`) and on one TV, but when using another TV the audio happens to be out-of-sync with the video by about 5 seconds! This does not happen to every video file on that TV, but turning the TV off and on again does not solve this problem.

Could this problem be solved by using a different video format/container, or by re-encoding all video files? Is there some video format/container known to have hardware/OS dependant issues like the ones I reported?

Comment: I'd avoid avi these days, mkv seems to have fewer sync issues. Also, use VLC as you can independently slide the audio against the video, during playback. [keys H/J or K/L can't remember right now]

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will try to convert a sample file to mkv then. However, I never have problems with syncing on my Linux box, and with `mplayer` I am pretty sure keys exist to move audio/video....